# How can I split a set of bytes into separate parts

Tags: linux, shell

```
$ du -b 1GB.bin
1048576000      1GB.bin

$ split --verbose -b 120M 1GB.bin && du -b *xa*
125829120       xaa
125829120       xab
125829120       xac
125829120       xad
125829120       xae
125829120       xaf
125829120       xag
125829120       xah
41943040        xai
```

How can I split or divide the `1048576000 bytes` above, or even bigger: `2GiB = 2147483648 bytes` or `3GiB = 3221225472 bytes` and so on, but without having to use the split utility, so that the result is exactly as above (per part is `120 MiB = 125829120 bytes`, except for the last part, `40 MiB = 41943040 bytes`) ?.

Comment: `dd bs=1M count=120 skip=0|120|240|...`

Comment: Depends on various things (1) What the Original file contains ( text , binary , images , video .... ? ) (2) What the output should contain ( Consistent viewable media ? ) (3) Why you want this ( to Process each file Individually ? to mail them ? to join them later ? ) (4) Why `split` is not ok ( It will not give usable media format ? It is too slow ? ) (5) Etc. **It will be better to include more Context + Detail to your Post to get better Suggestions towards the Issue !**